# CLOB representation in Unitils dbunit dataset

Tags: integration-testing, dbunit, unitils

I have a clob column in my table. How do I represent it in the dbunit dataset xml, so that I can use it in my integration test?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [ReplacementDataSet](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/dataset/ReplacementDataSet.html)

Here is an example:

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_CLOB(COLUMN_CLOB  CLOB);
```

XML DataSet (file dataSet.xml):

```
<dataset>
   <table name="TABLE_CLOB">
      <column>COLUMN_CLOB</column>
      <row>
         <value>CLOB_1</value>
      </row>
   </table>
</dataset>
```

In your test method:

```
// Initialize one IDataSet from your dataset xml
InputStream expIn = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("dataSet.xml");
IDataSet xmlDataSet = new XmlDataSet(expIn);

// Initialize one ReplacementDataSet with previous xmlDataSet
ReplacementDataSet dataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(xmlDataSet);

// Make the replacements
dataSet.addReplacementObject("CLOB_1", YourClobObject);

// Insert the dataSet into the databaseTest
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(databaseTester.getConnection(), dataSet);
```

Hope it helps